# How to deal with correlation between classes in deep learning classification?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am not sure about how to deal with the situation where some of the classes in a deep learning classification network are correlated to each other.

For example, when classifying images, if the input is a pic of a dog, and the output label is a cat, then the loss should be lower than if the output label is an airplane or a bridge. I was wondering how cs people deal with this before, and if there is any paper I can refer to. Thank you!

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question for [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:**
You can't/shouldn't

**Long version:**
If, for your specific case, you can find a measurement to determine how close the classes are from each other, like this:

```
d[i,j] = f(L[i], L[j])
```

(where `d[i,j]` is the distance between the classes with labels `L[i]` and `L[j]` and `f` is a function of those 2 classes/labels) then you can incorporate this in your loss function, such that the loss will be greater if `d` is large and smaller if `d` is small.

However, in your example with cats/dogs/airplanes/bridges/... I can't believe there is a correct way to determine the distance between dog/cat or dog/bridge etc. If you really want to, you could of course manually decide that for example predicting a bridge is 3 times worse than predicting a dog if your image contains a cat:

```
d[cat,dog]=1
d[cat,bridge]=3
```

But I wouldn't recommend this at all.

When would I recommend this? If you have a number of classes *and a correlation matrix that correctly quantifies the correlation* between all classes.

Comment: Sorry cat and dog are not a good example. I do have this correlation matrix.

Comment: In that case you could create a custom loss function which takes this distance in account

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. How to create this loss function? Thanks!

Comment: Or what are the terms I should look up?

Comment: You can create a custom loss function by subclassing `keras.losses.Loss`. Take a look at [the implementation of built-in loss functions](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) to see how they are implemented.